# $rootScope Doesn't Update Every time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show the internet not available bar on every page when internet is not available.

I m using Ionic framework so decided to keep code on menu.html

here is my menu html code

```
<div class="cfg-internet-error text-center text-bold" ng-hide="$root.internet_active">Internet not available</div>
```

I m setting the $rootScope on .run

```
 $rootScope.internet_active = navigator.onLine;
    window.addEventListener("online", function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('isOnline', true);
        $rootScope.internet_active = true;
    }, true);

    window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('isOnline', false);
        $rootScope.internet_active = false;
    }, true);
```

What happens is if internet got disconnected the it will show the bar but when it again comes back it won't hide it back i have tried ng-if also and when ever i change the page it hide backs so i want real time data binding with view when ever value changes it should get change the view value also

Comment: These `window` events happen outside of Angular's context, so append `$rootScope.$apply()` to the handler function.

Comment: what is the `$broadcast` doing? Also note that event listener is not within angular

Comment: Seems like root scope not getting updated, try this angular wrapper to check connectivity:  http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/

Comment: Plus see my post that why should we use ngCordova wrappers of plugins, instead of plain javascript : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331268/use-navigator-geolocation-or-cordovageolocation-in-ionic/32331986#32331986

Comment: use a service for persistent objects.  `$rootScope` is often misused, it is not meant as a pseudo global access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two notes:

1. Use the Angular wrapper [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window).
2. Differentiate the development (PC) and production (native) environment.

For example:

```
var state,
    online = 'online',
    offline = 'offline';

if (ENV === 'production') {
    if ($cordovaNetwork.isOnline()) {
        state = online;
    }
    if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline()) {
        state = offline;
    }
}
else if (ENV === 'development') {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        state = online;
    }
    else {
        state = offline;
    }
}

addEventListener(online);
addEventListener(offline);

function addEventListener(status) {
    $window.addEventListener(status, function () {
        state = status;
        if (state === online) {
            // $rootScope.$broadcast("network online");
        }
        else if (state === offline) {
            // $rootScope.$broadcast("network offline");
        }
    }, false);
}
```

The Cordova plugin [url](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/).