# Cordova geolocation plugin getCurrentPosition deprecated

Tags: cordova, http, https, geolocation, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that is trying to use geolocation exactly as shown in the docs.

```
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
  .then(function (position) {
    //  do something
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // error
  });
```

But now it has stopped working and in the console gives me this warning.

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

This seems like a huge change to the w3c spec I am just surprised there is not a lot of documentation regarding it. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here.

The app is running on phones so it's listening on localhost naturally. It is talking to the server over http not https but I don't see why that would affect getting geo-coordinates

I am testing the app on the browser and as a cordova app on an ios device.

Comment: are you testing on a browser? geolocation is going to be deprecated on google chrome on non https websites, but that won't affect cordova apps

Comment: Yes I tested it on the browser and as an ios app

Comment: In your cordova application, the html files are locally installed or it display a distant website ? does that website use http or https ?

Comment: locally installed. I think by default ionic builds is using http. But it's local though so it shouldn't matter, would it?

Answer (score 2):

I am using HTML5 geolocation directly. But cordova plugin is just angular wrapper over it, as they say [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331268/use-navigator-geolocation-or-cordovageolocation-in-ionic).

Apparently browsers can not use geolocation from http pages any more. But for ionic this is issue only for livereload. [There](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1686) is some workaround described using http-proxy to have livereload working on https.

Running the app on device without livereload (i.e. 'ionic run android' without '-l' at the end) works fine.

Remember to run getCurrentPosition after deviceready event. For me this one works in one of the controllers:

```
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            console.info('deviceready fired!');
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                console.info('Location from Cordova:');
                console.info("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "; Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

When testing out your app in the chrome browser, just change the apps url (generally 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000) to localhost:3000

You will need to make sure your media policy supports it, but you will not get a security error.