# Powerful Features on Insecure Origins and Phonegap Desktop

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app, w3c-geolocation

I created a Phonegap project and I was testing it using Phonegap Desktop.

In the project I'm using Geolocation API.

In Chrome I'm getting

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

How can I configure Phonegap Desktop to make this work? What do I have to do make it work on an actual mobile?

I already added in `config.xml`:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that you can still use Phonegap Desktop, but instead of using the IP displayed on the server location, use localhost, like http://localhost:3000. Chrome does support Geolocation API without HTTPS for localhost.

Then on the device everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, [Chrome doesn't support Geolocation API without using HTTPS](https://mobiforge.com/news-comment/no-https-then-bye-bye-geolocation-in-chrome-50).

You might have to preview your App using the PhoneGap Developer (Mobile) App.

This [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33950313/6317398) states that the Geolocation API should work fine on mobile.

Comment: Actually I discovered that you can still use Phonegap Desktop. Chrome does support Geolocation API without HTTPS for localhost. So you have to access Phonegap Desktop like http://localhost:3000, instead of using the API.